# How to iterate through a list finding words of a Certain length?

Tags: python

Given a list for example,

```
F=['MIKE', 'BALL', 'FISH', 'BAT', 'BEAR', 'CAT', 'AT', 'ALLY']
```

How would I go about iterating through said list finding all words with a certain length inputted by the user? I thought it would be..

```
number=input("How long would you like your word to be?")
possible_words=[]
for word in F:
     if word(len)=number:
          possible_words+=word
```

Comment: That is a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

This will give you a `list` of words whose length is `N`

```
possible_words = [x for x in F if len(x) == N]
```

*Note that you have a `list`, not a dictionary*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `filter` here :

```
 filter(lambda x:len(x)==number, F)
```

**help(filter)**:

```
In [191]: filter?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function filter>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string

Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
or string, return the same type, else return a list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is "inferior" in terms of code size and overall elegance to the other answers, its resemblance to the original code might help in understanding the faults of that
implementation.

```
F=['MIKE', 'BALL', 'FISH', 'BAT', 'BEAR', 'CAT', 'AT', 'ALLY']

number=input("How long would you like your word to be?")
possible_words=[]
for word in F:
    if len(word) == number:
        possible_words.append(word)
```

To check the length of a string, you use len(string) and not string(len). possible_words is a list and to add an element to it, you use .append() and not +=. += can be used to increase a number or add a single character to a string. Remember to use double equals (==) and not single (=) when doing comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in filter function.

```
print filter(lambda word: len(word) == N, F)
```